# High resolution stereoscopic 360 videos in A-Frame

Tags: aframe, stereoscopy

upon searching for a way to render stereoscopic videos in a-frame i stumbled upon the aframe-stereoscopic-component. The problem is, according to an open issue from 2019 [https://github.com/oscarmarinmiro/aframe-stereo-component], this component is unable to render anything beyond 1920x1920. The component itself hasnt been updated since 2017. This would pose a problem for our project. My question now is this: is this still the only/the preferred way to render stereoscopic videos in a-frame, and if that's so, is there a known way to overcome this limitation?

~Alex